# Non-blocking asynchronous HTTP requests

Tags: 8

I need to send asynchronous and non-blocking POST HTTP requests from a Drupal service.

Using Drupal 7, I used [HTTP Parallel Request](https://www.drupal.org/project/httprl) which worked fine.

But this module is not available on Drupal 8. And it seems that the default D8 HTTP Client, Guzzle, doesn't allow to do this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956516/send-asynchronous-request-without-waiting-the-response-using-guzzle.

Is there some way I can achieve that with Drupal 8 ?

**Edit**: If I don't find how to do it with Drupal mechanisms, I will go with this [fsockopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587514/php-fire-and-forget-post-request)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing a custom function on the base of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587514/php-fire-and-forget-post-request) :

```
private function async( $method, $url, $params = array() ){
    // Get URL parts
    $url_parts = parse_url( $url );

    // If needed, append params to query url
    if( $method === 'GET' ){
        $url .= '?' . http_build_query( $params );
    }

    // Open socket
    $port = isset( $url_parts['port'] ) ? $url_parts['port'] : 80;
    $fp = fsockopen( $url_parts['host'], $port, $errno, $errstr, 30 );

    // Build HTTP request
    $request = $method." ".$url." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request.= "Host: ".$url_parts['host'].":".$port."\r\n";
    $request.= "Connection: Close\r\n";
    if( $method === 'POST' || $method === 'DELETE' ){
        $post_string = Json::encode( $params );
        $request.= "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $request.= "Content-Length: ".strlen( $post_string )."\r\n";
        $request.= "\r\n";
        if( isset($post_string) ){
            $request.= $post_string;
        }
    } else {
        $request.= "\r\n";
    }

    // Send request and immediately close the pointer
    fwrite($fp, $request);
    fclose($fp);
}
```